# swift sqlite count+where always reutrns 0

Tags: swift, sqlite

i have problems using SQlite for Swift with `COUNT` and `WHERE`.

My Code:

```
let stmtString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Items WHERE codestring LIKE '%\(code)%'"    
let stmt = try self.connection?.prepare("\(stmtString)")

if let stmt = stmt {
    for row in stmt {
        print(row)
    }
}
```

the result contains 1 value(as it should) but it is 0.
Both `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Items"` and `"SELECT * FROM Items WHERE codestring LIKE '%\(code)%'"` work as they should, but i don't want to calculate it in my code in hopes of better performance. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So, the item existed in the table doesn't confirm the rule you wrote:

`codestring LIKE '%\(code)%'` check it more carefully

Simple `"SELECT * FROM Items` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scalar` instead of `prepare` for aggregate functions [see the doc](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#aggregation)

```
let stmt = try self.connection?.scalar("\(stmtString)")
```

Comment: @Ginso any feedback on this?